# Как можно стиснуть или же оптимизировать код на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

Можно ли упростить или оптимизировать следующий код?

```
const nav = document.querySelector('nav'),
  navList = nav.querySelectorAll('li'),
  totalNavList = navList.length,
  allSection = document.querySelectorAll('.section'),
  totalSection = allSection.length;

for (let i = 0; i < totalNavList; i++) {
  const a = navList[i].querySelector('a');
  a.addEventListener('click', function() {
    //remove back section Class
    for (let i = 0; i < totalSection; i++) {
      allSection[i].classList.remove('back-section');
    }

    for (let j = 0; j < totalNavList; j++) {
      if (navList[j].querySelector('a').classList.contains('active')) {
        //add back section Class
        allSection[j].classList.add('back-section');
      }

      navList[j].querySelector('a').classList.remove('active');
    }

    this.classList.add('active');

    showSection(this);
  })
}
```

Буду очень благодарен что поможете)

Comment: что делает данный код? Что именно не устраивает в нем в текущий момент?

Comment: А можете предоставить структуру HTML?